# Mapping of Conditional Rendering in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a component in React Native that involves a map and markers that corresponds to certain locations. Some markers have multiple items/images that are supposed to render, while others have one or none. I can make it render on each of the markers but I can't get my items to render on a marker when there are multiple.

If I run a console log, location 105 for example with have 5 in the array, 4 at location 104, location 101 will have 1, and 106 will have 0. I want to make it so that it will return a 5 logos in 105, 4 at 104 1 in 101, etc.

Currently I can get it to return the text of Hello at each of locations, but this is not what I'm trying to do. I'm having trouble with the conditional mapping.

```js
addSupporters(markerLocation, teamImages){
    var teamLogos = []
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.supportersGroups.MLS.length; i++) { 

      if (this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[i].homebar == markerLocation.MapMarker.id){
        

        teamLogos.push(this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[i])

                return(
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[i].name}</Text>
        <Image
          style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
          source={teamImages[this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[i].id]}
        />
      </View>
    )
      }     
    }
  }
```

Currently it will render the first item that meets the condition, but I would like it to render all of the items that meet the condition. So whenever the this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[i].homebar is equal to the markerLocation.MapMarker.id it adds them to the teamLogos array and then the array is mapped. So if there are 3 locations that meet the array, then it will look like this for this specific markerLocation:

```js
              <View>
            <Text>{this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[0].name}</Text>
            <Image
              style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
              source={teamImages[this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[0].id]}
            />
<Text>{this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[4].name}</Text>
            <Image
              style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
              source={teamImages[this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[4].id]}
            />
<Text>{this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[6].name}</Text>
            <Image
              style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
              source={teamImages[this.props.supportersGroups.MLS[6].id]}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO! You can help other people help you better it can be helpful to formulate a clear question as to what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry. I was trying to be concise without posting my whole component. I made an update that will hopefully be a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

When we call `addSupporters()` can return an object which satisfies has values of  `this.props.supportersGroups.MLS` where `Groups.MLS[i].homebar is equal to the markerLocation.MapMarker.id` and pass this array to be displayed. For that change your addSupporters function as,

```
addSupporters(markerLocation, teamImages){
    var teamLogos = []
    this.props.supportersGroups.MLS.filter((mls)=>mls.homebar == markerLocation.MapMarker.id)
      }     
    }
    return teamLogos;
  }
```

and in render call the `addSupporters()`with correct parameters and,

```
render(){
let teamLogos = addSupporters(markerLocation, teamImages)
return(
...
{
   teamLogos.map((logo)=><View>
        <Text>{logo.name}</Text>
        <Image
          style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
          source={logo.id]}
        />
      </View>)
}
```